# Laravel Auth protected pages and Facebook share button

Tags: facebook, laravel

I have a news website where some articles are free for read for everyone, while some others are password protected via middleware.
If user is not logged in and try to read a protected article, it will be redirected to login page.

So i want to add a facebook share button for every article, but on those protected by the middleware the facebook crawler is also redirected to login page, grabbing the wrong metadata.

Any suggestion on how i can provide the crawler the right metadata about the article i'm currently watching?

Thanks

Comment: You can check if  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] is equal to 'facebook'.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
Solved by adding to middleware:

`if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], array(
   'facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
   'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
   'Facebot (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
  )))
  {
   return $next($request);
  }`

Comment: You're welcome. Basically you sniff out the User Agent of the crawler.

Comment: Seeing stuff shared on their friend’s timelines that on click only redirects them to the login page of a service they probably don’t even have an account for will likely just frustrate a lot of users. If your stuff is not public, then sharing it doesn’t make the most sense IMHO.

Comment: You are totally right. I'm just a developer adn i do as customer wants. In fact i think that this share thing is only to lure some subscribers to theirs site

Comment: What is the website?